# How to add a proper escape sequence character into string

Tags: python, json

I have defined variable 'a' with a value of a dictionary as a string.
Got an error when trying to load that string as json.

```
>>> a = '{"key":"^~\\&"}'
>>> data = json.loads(a, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 352, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 9 (char 8)
>>>
```

Is there a way to make this happen

Comment: with raw string: `a = r'{"key":"^~\\&"}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using raw strings avoids that python "eats" one backslash, and then loading works:

```
>>> a = r'{"key":"^~\\&"}'
>>> print(json.loads(a))
{'key': '^~\\&'}
```

the backslash is still doubled because of the representation of the string but here:

```
>>> print(json.loads(a)["key"])
^~\&
```

it works fine

Of course, if your data already contains the string in question, raw strings won't help. In that case use `replace`:

```
>>> a = '{"key":"^~\\&"}'  # wrong
>>> a = a.replace("\\","\\\\")
>>> print(json.dumps(json.loads(a)))
{"key": "^~\\&"}
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with strings which include backslashes you should always use raw string literals:
(just put `r` before the string)

```
>>> a = r'{"key":"^~\\&"}'
>>> data = json.loads(a, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```